# Google Charts column chart gives Object [object Array] has no method 'getColumnType' when opened

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

When I open the following HTML document that contains a Google Charts column chart, I get the following error on a blank screen: Object [object Array] has no method 'getColumnType' ... I've tried the suggestions posted on similar questions on this website, but I haven't made any progress. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <title>Theme park prices</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){

            var data = [['Year', 'Disney', 'SeaWorld', 'Universal'], ['2013', 95, 100, 102]];

            var options = 
            {
                title:"Theme Park Prices",
                width:600, 
                height:400,
                hAxis: {title: "Year"},
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('priceChart'));

            function drawChart()
            {
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }

            drawChart();

        });

</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="priceChart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;margin: 0 auto;"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Be careful about trailing commas.  The hAxis property of your options should not have a comma after it, though some browsers are OK with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an obscure error message that should be fixed.  But the solution is simple, it turns out.  The chart.draw() method needs a DataTable object, not just an array of arrays.  So your data assignment should be like this:

```
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
         [['Year', 'Disney', 'SeaWorld', 'Universal'], ['2013', 95, 100, 102]]);
```